# Show half of the values on x-axis with ggplot and scale_x_discrete

Tags: r, ggplot2, xscale

I have a dataframe:

```
dput(df):

structure(list(Date = c("2008-11-28", "2008-12-31", "2009-01-30", 
"2009-02-27", "2009-03-31", "2009-04-30", "2009-05-29", "2009-06-30", 
"2009-07-31", "2009-08-31", "2009-09-30", "2009-10-30", "2009-11-30", 
"2009-12-31", "2010-01-29", "2010-02-26", "2010-03-31", "2010-04-30", 
"2010-05-31", "2010-06-30", "2010-07-30", "2010-08-31", "2010-09-30", 
"2010-10-29", "2010-11-30", "2010-12-31", "2011-01-31", "2011-02-28", 
"2011-03-31", "2011-04-29", "2011-05-31", "2011-06-30", "2011-07-29", 
"2011-08-31", "2011-09-30", "2011-10-31", "2011-11-30", "2011-12-30", 
"2012-01-31", "2012-02-29", "2012-03-30", "2012-04-30", "2012-05-31", 
"2012-06-29", "2012-07-31", "2012-08-31", "2012-09-28", "2012-10-31", 
"2012-11-30", "2012-12-31", "2013-01-31", "2013-02-28", "2013-03-29", 
"2013-04-30", "2013-05-31", "2013-06-28", "2013-07-31", "2013-08-30", 
"2013-09-30", "2013-10-31", "2013-11-29", "2008-11-28", "2008-12-31", 
"2009-01-30", "2009-02-27", "2009-03-31", "2009-04-30", "2009-05-29", 
"2009-06-30", "2009-07-31", "2009-08-31", "2009-09-30", "2009-10-30", 
"2009-11-30", "2009-12-31", "2010-01-29", "2010-02-26", "2010-03-31", 
"2010-04-30", "2010-05-31", "2010-06-30", "2010-07-30", "2010-08-31", 
"2010-09-30", "2010-10-29", "2010-11-30", "2010-12-31", "2011-01-31", 
"2011-02-28", "2011-03-31", "2011-04-29", "2011-05-31", "2011-06-30", 
"2011-07-29", "2011-08-31", "2011-09-30", "2011-10-31", "2011-11-30", 
"2011-12-30", "2012-01-31", "2012-02-29", "2012-03-30", "2012-04-30", 
"2012-05-31", "2012-06-29", "2012-07-31", "2012-08-31", "2012-09-28", 
"2012-10-31", "2012-11-30", "2012-12-31", "2013-01-31", "2013-02-28", 
"2013-03-29", "2013-04-30", "2013-05-31", "2013-06-28", "2013-07-31", 
"2013-08-30", "2013-09-30", "2013-10-31", "2013-11-29"), Variables = c("Korrelation Fond VS HEDGNAV Index", 
"Korrelation Fond VS HEDGNAV Index", "Korrelation Fond VS HEDGNAV Index", 
"Korrelation Fond VS HEDGNAV Index", "Korrelation Fond VS HEDGNAV Index", 
"Korrelation Fond VS HEDGNAV Index", "Korrelation Fond VS HEDGNAV Index", 
"Korrelation Fond VS HEDGNAV Index", "Korrelation Fond VS HEDGNAV Index", 
"Korrelation Fond VS HEDGNAV Index", "Korrelation Fond VS HEDGNAV Index", 
"Korrelation Fond VS HEDGNAV Index", "Korrelation Fond VS HEDGNAV Index", 
"Korrelation Fond VS HEDGNAV Index", "Korrelation Fond VS HEDGNAV Index", 
"Korrelation Fond VS HEDGNAV Index", "Korrelation Fond VS HEDGNAV Index", 
"Korrelation Fond VS HEDGNAV Index", "Korrelation Fond VS HEDGNAV Index", 
"Korrelation Fond VS HEDGNAV Index", "Korrelation Fond VS HEDGNAV Index", 
"Korrelation Fond VS HEDGNAV Index", "Korrelation Fond VS HEDGNAV Index", 
"Korrelation Fond VS HEDGNAV Index", "Korrelation Fond VS HEDGNAV Index", 
"Korrelation Fond VS HEDGNAV Index", "Korrelation Fond VS HEDGNAV Index", 
"Korrelation Fond VS HEDGNAV Index", "Korrelation Fond VS HEDGNAV Index", 
"Korrelation Fond VS HEDGNAV Index", "Korrelation Fond VS HEDGNAV Index", 
"Korrelation Fond VS HEDGNAV Index", "Korrelation Fond VS HEDGNAV Index", 
"Korrelation Fond VS HEDGNAV Index", "Korrelation Fond VS HEDGNAV Index", 
"Korrelation Fond VS HEDGNAV Index", "Korrelation Fond VS HEDGNAV Index", 
"Korrelation Fond VS HEDGNAV Index", "Korrelation Fond VS HEDGNAV Index", 
"Korrelation Fond VS HEDGNAV Index", "Korrelation Fond VS HEDGNAV Index", 
"Korrelation Fond VS HEDGNAV Index", "Korrelation Fond VS HEDGNAV Index", 
"Korrelation Fond VS HEDGNAV Index", "Korrelation Fond VS HEDGNAV Index", 
"Korrelation Fond VS HEDGNAV Index", "Korrelation Fond VS HEDGNAV Index", 
"Korrelation Fond VS HEDGNAV Index", "Korrelation Fond VS HEDGNAV Index", 
"Korrelation Fond VS HEDGNAV Index", "Korrelation Fond VS HEDGNAV Index", 
"Korrelation Fond VS HEDGNAV Index", "Korrelation Fond VS HEDGNAV Index", 
"Korrelation Fond VS HEDGNAV Index", "Korrelation Fond VS HEDGNAV Index", 
"Korrelation Fond VS HEDGNAV Index", "Korrelation Fond VS HEDGNAV Index", 
"Korrelation Fond VS HEDGNAV Index", "Korrelation Fond VS HEDGNAV Index", 
"Korrelation Fond VS HEDGNAV Index", "Korrelation Fond VS HEDGNAV Index", 
"Korrelation Fond VS OMXN40 INDEX", "Korrelation Fond VS OMXN40 INDEX", 
"Korrelation Fond VS OMXN40 INDEX", "Korrelation Fond VS OMXN40 INDEX", 
"Korrelation Fond VS OMXN40 INDEX", "Korrelation Fond VS OMXN40 INDEX", 
"Korrelation Fond VS OMXN40 INDEX", "Korrelation Fond VS OMXN40 INDEX", 
"Korrelation Fond VS OMXN40 INDEX", "Korrelation Fond VS OMXN40 INDEX", 
"Korrelation Fond VS OMXN40 INDEX", "Korrelation Fond VS OMXN40 INDEX", 
"Korrelation Fond VS OMXN40 INDEX", "Korrelation Fond VS OMXN40 INDEX", 
"Korrelation Fond VS OMXN40 INDEX", "Korrelation Fond VS OMXN40 INDEX", 
"Korrelation Fond VS OMXN40 INDEX", "Korrelation Fond VS OMXN40 INDEX", 
"Korrelation Fond VS OMXN40 INDEX", "Korrelation Fond VS OMXN40 INDEX", 
"Korrelation Fond VS OMXN40 INDEX", "Korrelation Fond VS OMXN40 INDEX", 
"Korrelation Fond VS OMXN40 INDEX", "Korrelation Fond VS OMXN40 INDEX", 
"Korrelation Fond VS OMXN40 INDEX", "Korrelation Fond VS OMXN40 INDEX", 
"Korrelation Fond VS OMXN40 INDEX", "Korrelation Fond VS OMXN40 INDEX", 
"Korrelation Fond VS OMXN40 INDEX", "Korrelation Fond VS OMXN40 INDEX", 
"Korrelation Fond VS OMXN40 INDEX", "Korrelation Fond VS OMXN40 INDEX", 
"Korrelation Fond VS OMXN40 INDEX", "Korrelation Fond VS OMXN40 INDEX", 
"Korrelation Fond VS OMXN40 INDEX", "Korrelation Fond VS OMXN40 INDEX", 
"Korrelation Fond VS OMXN40 INDEX", "Korrelation Fond VS OMXN40 INDEX", 
"Korrelation Fond VS OMXN40 INDEX", "Korrelation Fond VS OMXN40 INDEX", 
"Korrelation Fond VS OMXN40 INDEX", "Korrelation Fond VS OMXN40 INDEX", 
"Korrelation Fond VS OMXN40 INDEX", "Korrelation Fond VS OMXN40 INDEX", 
"Korrelation Fond VS OMXN40 INDEX", "Korrelation Fond VS OMXN40 INDEX", 
"Korrelation Fond VS OMXN40 INDEX", "Korrelation Fond VS OMXN40 INDEX", 
"Korrelation Fond VS OMXN40 INDEX", "Korrelation Fond VS OMXN40 INDEX", 
"Korrelation Fond VS OMXN40 INDEX", "Korrelation Fond VS OMXN40 INDEX", 
"Korrelation Fond VS OMXN40 INDEX", "Korrelation Fond VS OMXN40 INDEX", 
"Korrelation Fond VS OMXN40 INDEX", "Korrelation Fond VS OMXN40 INDEX", 
"Korrelation Fond VS OMXN40 INDEX", "Korrelation Fond VS OMXN40 INDEX", 
"Korrelation Fond VS OMXN40 INDEX", "Korrelation Fond VS OMXN40 INDEX", 
"Korrelation Fond VS OMXN40 INDEX"), Value = c(0.543281082364437, 
0.527712775086864, 0.408808506706841, 0.429295911936136, 0.413869805084106, 
0.420679623586744, 0.486699140272165, 0.489646951704357, 0.482167209693269, 
0.476479729549409, 0.470318758286474, 0.445944951970354, 0.443399322259001, 
0.450016066763416, 0.426480550286595, 0.423371569969272, 0.45695040799057, 
0.431834238396871, 0.467511327603749, 0.468313995662446, 0.497800239085846, 
0.483892272485929, 0.461639835904741, 0.510817807699252, 0.607556423633874, 
0.635324016630525, 0.677123446245495, 0.64944374391215, 0.699596537117267, 
0.719111914210672, 0.646823640421409, 0.704957947272873, 0.711475445475265, 
0.586745307486821, 0.470189153059282, 0.496157837064293, 0.42998988517485, 
0.410086396037883, 0.434712079537519, 0.451209820436262, 0.439204849230259, 
0.458968925612488, 0.413432511226888, 0.352720907440874, 0.345869742666471, 
0.334881763959464, 0.364193270299568, 0.349099808200996, 0.344120170458358, 
0.321312279605764, 0.36780909986839, 0.45673262559758, 0.441745479560392, 
0.472657754486699, 0.460230404194416, 0.439767509233639, 0.451917786933249, 
0.502203230669925, 0.506491068871301, 0.326404602073815, 0.370217685029334, 
0.718957249305725, 0.692112042544696, 0.653190037272512, 0.600562794023062, 
0.577038569091474, 0.732404727204883, 0.701073092028334, 0.70024367927988, 
0.72760615710821, 0.760476468119078, 0.76494346961595, 0.74516226659605, 
0.739882810581542, 0.747631786072444, 0.726091015017154, 0.701735263628067, 
0.702742836045239, 0.710111045287843, 0.709534887923479, 0.660085062138124, 
0.68714771636425, 0.692372537364393, 0.653723068520449, 0.60219048444321, 
0.611238847460719, 0.615532490318692, 0.629099995821728, 0.696641041953563, 
0.699678945834638, 0.586283865406429, 0.624290876602801, 0.670695507419494, 
0.659774721518298, 0.71774709033755, 0.744569380783438, 0.816379470202153, 
0.837499193100422, 0.836198005977033, 0.84080909869627, 0.855061699261408, 
0.853368178821269, 0.851320045495211, 0.851777606811136, 0.814170256202011, 
0.815730122501554, 0.816104542127919, 0.791916561887601, 0.789829046533777, 
0.798421955468353, 0.768092583652463, 0.775993885935737, 0.782511954882627, 
0.792300623324247, 0.788792623730908, 0.777178875667974, 0.77530100406966, 
0.784668152948575, 0.723029746336548, 0.694308712557347, 0.657753481204441, 
0.656521122619321)), .Names = c("Date", "Variables", "Value"), row.names = c(NA, 
-122L), class = "data.frame")
```

I then use ggplot:

```
 CorrelationsBenchPlot<-ggplot(corres24mDfMelt, aes(x=Date,y=Value,group=Variables))+
  geom_line(aes(linetype=Variables,colour=Variables), size=1)+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0.3,0.9,0.1),limits=c(0.3,0.9))+
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = corres24mDfMelt$Date[c(TRUE,FALSE)])+
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("black", "red", "green"))+theme_gdocs()+
  theme(axis.text.x  = element_text(angle=-90, hjust=0.5, size=8,colour="black",face="bold"),
        axis.text.y  = element_text(size=8,colour="black",face="bold"),
        legend.text = element_text(colour="black", size = 12, face = "bold"),
        legend.background = element_rect(fill="gray90", size=.5, linetype="dotted"), 
        plot.title = element_text(size = rel(1.6),face = "bold"),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        legend.title=element_blank(),
        legend.position=c(0.3, 0.11), 
        legend.position="none",
        legend.box="vertical")+
  labs(title = "2 Year Rolling Correlation\n")
```

So I want to show each second character value on x-axis by using `scale_x_discrete(breaks = corres24mDfMelt$Date[c(TRUE,FALSE)])`, but it doesnt work and I get all the x-axis values.

What am I doing wrong?

Best Regards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values in `corres24mDfMelt$Date` are not unique but duplicated (you have two values per date). Hence, the command `corres24mDfMelt$Date[c(TRUE,FALSE)]` still returns all possible values.

You have to use the `unique` dates as a basis:

```
scale_x_discrete(breaks = unique(corres24mDfMelt$Date)[c(TRUE,FALSE)])
```

[image]